# WKInterfaceLabel in custom WKInterfaceTable row unwrapping to nil

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, wkinterfacetable, wkinterfacelabel

The title sums it up. I've tried disconnecting/reconnecting all the IBOutlets. Here's the code on my InterfaceController where I set up the WKInterfaceTable:

```
func setupLoadingTable () {
    self.myTable.setNumberOfRows(1, withRowType:"universalRowID")

    for (var i = 0; i<self.myTable.numberOfRows; i++){
        var row = self.myTable.rowControllerAtIndex(i) as! UniversalRowView
        row.mainTitle.setText("Hello world") //THIS THROWS AN ERROR
    }
}
```

Here's the code for my UniversalRowView which is my custom row class:

```
import WatchKit

class UniversalRowView: NSObject {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainTitle: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subTitle: WKInterfaceLabel!

}
```

The IBOutlets for the Table is properly connected. The row on Storyboard is set to type UniversalRowView and outlets for both labels are properly connected.

The line:

```
row.mainTitle.setText("Hello world")
```

throws the following error: **"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"**

Also, when I comment that code out, I don't see the stock WKInterfaceLabels on the simulator as they appear on the Storyboard. I feel like this is an error as well but I don't know what to make of it.

**Edit**: Calling setupLoadingTable() in willActivate()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out! It seems like there is an attribute in the view of both WKInterfaceTable and WKInterfaceLabel called "38mm Installed". The problem was, I was running the simulator on 42mm **but I only had 38mm checked**.

Once I checked both attributes, everything worked as planned!

Here's a screenshot of what I'm referring to:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and for me it was because I named IBOutlet for my WKInterfaceLabel `title` which is as it turns out also a name of a method in NSObject.

Comment: I encounter the same. However, I don't understand why "title" as a property is not proper when there is a title method? As far as I know, the title method is `func title(for: ABPerson!, identifier: String!)`, which can't be confused with "title" property.